# Doubling binary digits

Tags: python, algorithm, math, binary

How to double a number of binary digits in an integer? For example, if bin(x)="1001" then bin(y) must be "11000011". Is there any smart and fast algorithm ?

UPDATE: Here is an elegant solution:

```
''.join([''.join(i) for i in zip(X,X)])
```

where X is bin(int_x)[2:]

However, I am interested in a more faster way and for the integers of any size. Maybe an arithmetical transformation should help.

Comment: What should the output be for non-symmetric input, e.g. should input of 8 (b1000) give 3 (b00000011) or 192 (b11000000)?

Comment: If the input is b0 + 2*b1 + 4*b2 + 8*b3 + ... then I think that @psihodelia wants b0 + 2*b0 + 4*b1 + 8*b1 + 16*b2 + 32*b2 + ...

Comment: Use INTERCAL - it's one of the basic operators. `DO :1 <- :1¢:1`

Comment: For elegency, what about `''.join(chain(*zip(X, X)))`? Remember to `from itertools import chain`. `:]`

Comment: ok, that's a very odd definition of "Double"... My first thought was "umm... x << 1?"

Comment: I'm interested as to the application of this? Somewhat off topic, yes, but I'd love to know what need you're supplying in doing this - you know, just out of interest..

Comment: `bin(int_x)[2:]` can also be written as `'{0:b}'.format(int_x)` although that is admittedly longer

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here's one way that should be reasonably fast:  convert your number to a binary string, then reinterpret the result as being in base 4.  Now to make sure that all the '1's are doubled properly, multiply the result by 3.

```
>>> x = 9
>>> bin(x)
'0b1001'
>>> y = int(bin(x)[2:], 4)*3
>>> bin(y)
'0b11000011'
```

Comment: Nice one! Took me some time to get it.

Answer (score 16):

(Reference http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#Interleave64bitOps):

If your number is below 256, you may use

```
@magic
def double_digits_holger8(x):
    m = (x * 0x0101010101010101 & 0x8040201008040201) * 0x0102040810204081
    return ((m >> 49) & 0x5555) | ((m >> 48) & 0xAAAA)
```

and if it is below 65536,

```
@more_magic
def double_digits_binmag16(x):
    x = (x | x << 8) & 0x00FF00FF
    x = (x | x << 4) & 0x0F0F0F0F
    x = (x | x << 2) & 0x33333333
    x = (x | x << 1) & 0x55555555
    return x | x << 1
```

Comparison with other solutions (the function must take an integer and return an integer for fair comparison):

```
Method        Time per 256 calls
--------------------------------
Do nothing        46.2 usec 
Holger8          256   usec
BinMag16         360   usec
Mark             367   usec # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928886/doubling-binary-digits/2929198#2929198
Max              720   usec # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928886/doubling-binary-digits/2928938#2928938
Peter          1.08    msec # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928886/doubling-binary-digits/2928973#2928973
Phiµµ w/o Log  1.11    msec # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928886/doubling-binary-digits/2929106#2929106
Jim16          1.26    msec # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928886/doubling-binary-digits/2929038#2929038
Elegant        1.66    msec # int(''.join([''.join(i) for i in zip(X,X)]),2)
More Elegant   2.05    msec # int(''.join(chain(*zip(X, X))), 2)
```

Benchmark source code can be found in http://gist.github.com/417172.

Comment: +1 for more magic. You can get rid of some of the semi-colons. `;p`

Comment: I am interested more in an universal method for the long integers of any size.

Comment: Is there any specific reason to use the "magic" and "more_magic" decorators? Looking at your code, they seem to just pass the function (value) along without actually doing anything to it. Am I wrong in thinking that you might as well just have "magic" and "more_magic" be comments?

Comment: @KennyTM: Ah, I see. Thanks for the link. I think I'll keep it bookmarked.

Answer (score 11):

The straightforward solution just using integer arithmetic would be:

```
def doubledigits(n):
    result = 0
    power = 1
    while n > 0:
        if n%2==1:
            result += 3*power
        power *= 4
        n //= 2
    return result
```

Comment: It's much less elegant than using string (more code), but would also probably be much faster (especially as it's easily portable to c).

Comment: @Matthieu: It is faster only if it is really written in C.

Comment: Probably (I haven't benchmarked it) since hand-loops are notoriously slow in python in comparison to the built-in operations.

Comment: I have say, I dispute the idea that "elegant" equals "less code". That's a dangerous way to think. Conciseness is not necessarily the same thing as clarity. (That said, Mark Dickinson's answer is excellent.)

Answer (score 4):

any_number - int

str(n) - produces string from int.

str::replace(pattern, replaced_value) - replaces all patterns in string to replaced_value.

int(str) - makes int from string.

```
n=any_number
result_number = int(str(n).replace("0","00").replace("1","11"))
```

Comment: I am not sure it is fast, but it is ellegant. didn't notice it in question, but I commonly use python when I don't mind about speed. Anyway, why this shouldn't be fast? str::replace method replaces all entries in one traversal. So here are two traversals, 2 is only constant, the complexity is still O(N)

Comment: @Max: O-complexity doesn't tell about speed, it basically measures how your algorithm scales.

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't see Peter Milley's solution.

Comment: So if `n = 2335`... did you mean to write `bin(n)[2:]`?

Comment: Yes, I mean it, but here is written: "a number of binary digits". My English says that number contains only binary digits, not so?

Comment: I quote: «if `bin(x)="1001"` then `bin(y)` must be `"11000011"`», where `0b1001` is `9`. (Oh, you'll need also to use the base argument for the `int` call...)

Comment: you could double any string like this `''.join([c*2 for c in str(n)])`

Comment: IMO, Max's solution is the most elegant. I don't see a need to use complicated function for this, unless the use case warrants.

Comment: @Nick D, I will take it into account, tnx.

Comment: @Xavier Ho: I totally agree. All the other solutions take a non-trivial amount of brainpower to understand, for the saving of a trivial amount of CPU performance. Don't get me wrong, the "clever" solutions are very interesting to read (for the theory of it), but I'd probably end up using this solution in practice, unless microsecond performance was *truly* an issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ python2.6
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Mar 25 2010, 14:13:28)
>>> def dd(n): return eval("0b" + "".join(d * 2 for d in str(bin(n))[2:]))
...
>>> dd(9)
195
```

Comment: I know eval is evil, if you don't need to convert the result to decimal, you don't need it.

Comment: you don't need to use `eval` at all. `eval("0b" + ...)` is the same as `int(..., 2)`

Answer (score 0):

```
y = 0;
for(i = 15; i  >= 0; i--) {
    if((1 << i) & x) {
       y |= 3;
    }
    y <<= 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def doubledigits(x):
    from math import log
    print (bin(x))
    numdigits = x.bit_length()
    result = 1 << (numdigits*2)
    for i in range(numdigits, -1, -1):
        mask = 1 << i
        if (x & mask > 0):
            rmask = 0b11 << (2*i)
            result = result | rmask
    return result
```

should do it.

Comment: Compare this solution to Peter Milley's solution above. Which one is nicer?

Comment: Doesn't work for x = 0. Just use `x.bit_length()` instead of log.

Comment: @unbeli compare your comment to the others on this question - which is nicer? :P hey, as far as i'm concerned, at least he gave a working solution!